# Can't see the items on my ListBox

Tags: wpf, listbox

I trying to define ListBox that show all the element that i define in some collection.

The code:

```
public class Element
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } }

    public Element(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
}

public class ElementCollection
{
    public List<Element> Elements
    {
        get;
        set;  
    }
}





  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementCollection}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Element.Name}"/>
                 </StackPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I did 'DataContext' and all the data are in the right place.

What i did wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are `binding` to the class that holds the collection, not to the actual collection - try changing your `ItemSource` to be `{Binding ElementCollection.Elements}` instead. Also, your `Textbox` is bound to `Element.Name`, you dont need that, as it will look up for `Name` property in your item:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementCollection.Elements}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Take a look now, just spotted another thing that's wasn't right

Comment: Can you see any warnings in output ? I see you dont implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `Element` - can you add the code that you use to set the DataContext for your view ?

Comment: I add the INotifyPropertyChanging - and still don't work

Comment: did you notify the property has changed in `Element` ctor after setting the name ? `OnPropertyChanged("Name")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87061/discussion-between-horia-and-yanshof).